# Is there anyway to make vnc viewer function like Xming with allowing linux windows move freely about?

Tags: ssh, x11, vnc, remote-desktop, xming

I have a vncserver set up on my remote machine and am using vnc viewer to interact with that machine.

I am also used to doing the following: 1. Remote connecting to a machine with an ssh client like Putty and using Xming for X11 forward so that I can open linux programs but have them appear on my windows desktop and move about freely.

What I don't like about the vnc viewer is that linux programs have to 'stay' within the view viewer window, and there is essentially less screen space to interact programs with.

I am wondering if there is a way to get the kind of experience that I am used to with Xming but with vnc somehow?

I know I could use screen with a terminal, but I don't wan to do that. I want to use vnc somehow.

BTW, my operating system is Windows 7

Comment: See http://www.virtualgl.org/About/Background and the section "The VGL Transport", look for the word "seamless".

Answer (score 1):

[xpra](http://xpra.org) is screen for X11, and does exactly what you ask